# how to use jQuerys each with checking an image exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some source that actually drives me crazy...

First, I have a object like this:

```
var extensions  = {"jpg":".jpg","JPG":".JPG","png":".png","PNG":".PNG"};
```

Now I want to iterate the object to check if a image with one of these extensions exists. The source for this looks like:

```
var imgURL  = "some/path/";
var imgName = "myFileName";
var counter = 0; 

$.each(extensions, function( key, imgExtension ){

    var tmpImgUrl = imgURL + imgName + imgExtension;
    console.log('test');
    $( ".imageCheck" ).unbind().attr( "src", tmpImgUrl ).error( function(){
        console.log( tmpImgUrl );
        counter++;
        if( counter >= Object.keys( extensions ).length){
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This each should take the image name and try to test if there is an error for each extension. Actually it does what it should do. Only thing is, counter doesn't gets counted up and the console log appears wrong.

I expact the log should look like:

```
test
some/path/myFileName.jpg
test
some/path/myFileName.JPG
test...
```

and so on. But it appers like:

```
test
test
test
test
some/path/myFileName.jpg
some/path/myFileName.JPG
...
```

actually I want to use the image check to return a break (false) for the each so not all extensions get checked. (performance)

And also I really need the counter when exiting the check part....

Any guesses what going wrong here ?

Comment: When you use .each, you instantly start to test all types, they won't test one by one.

Comment: how can it test all types when i only use one ? i mean my imageCheck isn't an each at all.

Comment: is `$( ".imageCheck" )` a collection of elements...or just one element?

Comment: actually its just an empty image container `<img class='imageCheck' src='' />`

Comment: sorry, had a worng copie :D I am testing since 2 hours. Actually there was a `.unbind()` to avoid the multiple src'es. But this does none to the end goal.

Comment: would be better just to create a new image element each time

Comment: Your log is fine. You call `.error`, which is an async function, it'll take time to check if the browser can load the image, and if no, it'll run the callback **later**, after your `console.log` has been executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a loader to do the image test.

1. Init the `index` to test.
2. Create an `<img>`, add `onload` and `onerror` behavior. `onload` will notify the user, or you can event let the loader accept callbacks for onload to call it, `onerror` will try to load image with next type.
3. The `tryLoad` function first check if `index` is equal to `extensions.length`, if it is, which means all possibles are failed, notify user the image load failed, and do some fail fallback or something.

   Otherwise, it use current `index` with give fileName and `url` to create imagepath, set it to `img.src` and increase the `index` for next attempts.
4. call the `tryload` to start the process.
5. Now the image stops attempt when current `url` is valid, and will try the extesions one-by-one until no other can be used.

```
// Inits, can also be put into the loader.
var extensions = ['.jpg', '.JPG', '.png', '.PNG'];
var imgUrl = "some/path/";

var loader = function(fileName, success, fail) {
  // Start at first image type.
  var index = 0;

  // Create a img for loading.
  var $image = $('<img>');
  
  // Add success and fail behavior to the image.
  $image
    .load(function() {
      // Do some notification or....
      console.log('success', $image.attr('src'));
     
      // If you give a success callback, call it
      // Or you can write the logic here. 
      if ($.isFunction(success)) {
        success();
      }
    })
    .error(function() {
      console.log('fail', $image.attr('src'));
      // Try to load next image
      tryLoad(index);
    });
  
  // The function for attempts.
  var tryLoad = function() {
    // When all attemps tried.
    if (index === extensions.length) {
      alert('Boom, all failed');
      // Do some fallbacks....
      // $image.remove();

      // If you give a fail callback, call it
      // Or you can write the logic here. 
      if ($.isFunction(fail)) {
        fail();
      }
      return;
    }
    
    // Create url to load.
    var tmpImgUrl = imgURL + fileName + extensions[index];
    console.log('test', tmpImgUrl);
    $image.attr('src', tmpImgUrl);
    ++index;
  };

  // Start the first attempt.
  tryLoad();

  // return jquery wrapper of image. It'll have image only if any of the test is passed.
  return $image;
};
```

Comment: ill give this a try. But it has `.error()` as well and that what klenium sayed sounds logic :) but I will try this loader...

Answer (score -3):

You won't want to use jQuery's .each to loop through an object - the proper way to do this is using javascript's for in loop.

Looping through your extensions object should look like this:

```
for(var key in extensions){
    console.log("Key", key, "Value",extensions.key);
}
```

You can then do whatever it is you need with those keys or values using the above looping construct.

Comment: `each` and `for` will accomplish the same thing so you haven't provided valid reason not to use `each`. In addition this doesn't answer the question

Comment: actually the same result

Comment: `$.each()` actually has advantages over plain `for... in`, like the inner scope created by the iteration callback.